# Is the Endurance implant "free?"

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

By this, I mean, the Endurance implant gives you +1 Endurance. The number of implants you can buy is limited by your Endurance score. Does the +1 you get from this implant allow you to get an extra implant?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the answer is, "no." Adding an Endurance implant will take up one of your original Endurance slots. However, it does confer the hit point bonus.

Also, in case anyone asks, adding an Intelligence implant does grant more skill points at level-up.

[Source](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_implants)

Comment: You should have asked a separate question about the intelligence item.  You're not rep-greedy enough.  In all honesty that would show up better in search.

Comment: I'll let someone else ask that one and get the deserved rep. :)

Comment: The comment about Intelligence implants is untrue. It does grant more skill points at level up. I don't know why you'd think otherwise. It does not however, do so retroactively.

Comment: @LessPop: At the time this was written, the Wiki was reading differently. Updated answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

No, but the Intense Training Perk - when applied to Endurance - does allow you to get another implant.  This allows you to pick up 2 SPECIAL points for the price of a single perk.